# UIImageView with alpha and MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a UIImageView on top of an MPMoviePlayerController. The UIImageView is set to alpha 0.6 in order to show the movie underneath it a bit. However, I'm noticing performance issues on the 1st-gen iPad and iPhone 4, but it works smoothly on an iPhone 5.

Do you think it would improve performance to somehow make the movie have an alpha of 0.6, instead of the UIImageView, and then place the movie on top of the UIImageView? If so, how can I save the movie with an alpha or transparency to achieve this?

Comment: are you sure its the alpha that is causing the performance issues? if you were to scale it down a bit (just so you can see the video) and remove the alpha, would it perform better?

Comment: The UIImageView is a background image the same width and height as the video. When I remove the video completely, it performs better. I can try leaving the video, and removing the alpha to see if it performs better. But then the desired effect of seeing the video animation would be lost.

Comment: You're right, even with alpha 1.0, it's slow on the iPad. But if I remove the video, it's pretty good.

Comment: your image could be too high def. How big is it? is it a photo? if so consider using .jpg instead of .png if youre not already.

Comment: just a jpg, covers whole screen, 142kb retina, 46kb regular